# Why is my click region for a circle layer in Mapbox offset to the right?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, react

I'm using mapbox gl js in a react framework to create we web map app. I have added a circle layer to the map and have a problem where the clickable `mouseenter` area of the circle is offset to the right. Below are two images that represent this behavior. The crosshair cursor is default and the pointer cursor is on `mouseenter`.

[image]

[image]

I came across this github issue that kind of relates to my issue: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/9467

I've tried removing items from my `div` tags like recommended in that github post but haven't been able to work around this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by isolating my map reference in it's own `div` as some alluded to in the github issue I mentioned.

Before

```js
  return (
      <Col className="map-container" ref={mapContainer} >
       <VerticalMenu
          changeVisibilityState={changeVisibilityState}
          changeScaleState={changeScaleState}
          geocoderNational={geocoderNational}
          geocoderAdmin={geocoderAdmin}
        />
```

After

```js
  return (
      <Col className="map-container" >
        <div ref={mapContainer}></div>
        <VerticalMenu
          changeVisibilityState={changeVisibilityState}
          changeScaleState={changeScaleState}
          geocoderNational={geocoderNational}
          geocoderAdmin={geocoderAdmin}
        />
```